# Объясните, что значит спрятать работу с json за интерфейсами?

Tags: java

Пытаюсь сделать простенькую библиотечку для работы с API
99% этой библиотечки это обычные POJO классы

Плюс есть пара статических методов в классе Util "toPojo(json, class)" и "toJson(object)"

Но мне посоветовали переделать эти в методы в: "цитирую"

> я бы спрятал работу с json за интерфейсами, что бы можно было легко поменять библиотеки если захочиться, тогда отпадет проблема с дублированием, потому что тогда тебя не будет парить как работает например либа для парсинга и не будет влиять на твои решения в проектировании
> т.е отделить инфраструктуру от логики либы
>
> например делаешь интерфейс который условно скрывает парсинг.
> Что мы обычно парсим? строку, а что мы обычно получаем? объект
>
> значит можно сделать метод в интерфейсе
> например public T parse(String raw)
>
> и везде в коде где у тебя парсинг ты работаешь с этим интерфейсом а не с конкретным парсером, а всю работу по парсингу прячешь в отдельном пакете и в классе реализающем твой интерфейс
>
> когда все так отделено тебя не волнует то, как работает та или иная либа

Сообственно вопрос, может ли кто-то показать пример такой реализации и немного более подробно ее разъяснить?

Comment: Правило трех. Пока у вас нет минимум трех разных программ/пользователей библиотеки - это только лишние обертки абстракции и это вам не нужно.

Answer (score 4):

От вас хотят следующего.

```
interface Json {
     <T> T toPojo(String value, Class<T> clazz);

     String toJson(Object obj);
}
```

И реализации этого интерфейса.